# Count many text inputs and do something when each is set

Tags: jquery

I have many many textbox inputs on a page, I'm attempting to check that each is set in a loop, when each is set I'm attempting to run a function.

I have the following code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

var count_input = 0;
var count_valid_input = 0;

 $("#weekly-suppliers").change(function(){
            call_calculation(); //
    });

    function call_calculation(){
            $('input[class=enquiry]').each(function(){
                count_input ++;
                var text_value = $(this).val();
                if(text_value != '') //remember, data has already been sanitized!
                {
                    count_valid_input ++;
                    console.log('input: ' + count_input);
                    console.log('valid: ' + count_valid_input);
                }
            })
            if(count_input == count_valid_input){
                console.log('do calc');
                do_calculation();
            }
            else {
                count_input = 0;
                count_valid_input = 0;
            }
        }
});
```

This loops through each text input with the class enquiry. A counter is incremented for each element, another counter is initiated for each element that is set. If these two counters match, then a function is run. I'm nevver reaching this point though, could anyone suggest why?

The function call_calculation is called in each text input change event. I have lots of these functions in the script, for each text input:

```
 $("#weekly-suppliers").change(function(){
                call_calculation(); //
        });
```

So essentially when the number of valid inputs matches the number of text inputs with the class `enquiry`, the function `do_calculation();` should be called, however it is never met. Could anyone suggest why?

Comment: @xec updated the question

Comment: do some debugging. after your loop finishes log `count_valid_input` and `count_input`. if what you say is true then you'll find that they don't match, and you can do some further debugging with `text_value` from there

Comment: [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every): `if ($('input.enquiry').get().every((i) => $(i).val() !== "")) { do_calculation() }`